# Wolfram-Alpha's choice of $k$ in a complex logarithm

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, wolfram-alpha

I'm puzzling on this complex integral:

$$ \int \frac{2ie^{it}}{2e^{it} - 1}dt = \log(2e^{it} -1)$$

The numerator is the derivative of the divisor, so the primitive is the log of the divisor.

When you ask Wolfram-Alpha to compute the integral over the range $0..2\pi$:

$$\left. \log(2e^{it} -1) \right|_0^{2\pi}$$

[The answer is $2i\pi$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20%282%2ai%2ae%5E%28i%2at%29%29/%282%2ae%5E%28i%2at%29-1%29dt,%20t=0..2%2api).  And that's probably a valid answer:

$$\log(2e^{i2\pi}-1) - \log(2e^{i0}-1) = \ln(1) - \ln(1) + 2k\pi i = ..., -2\pi i, 0, 2\pi i, ... $$

Still in this case, the canonical answer should be the one where $k=0$. When you ask Wolfram-Alpha for $log(1)$, it returns $0$, and not $2\pi i$.

Why does Wolfram-Alpha return $2 \pi i$ and not $0$ for the integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram's answer is correct, and the only correct answer here. If you consider the integral as a function of the upper bound,

$$I(x) = \int_0^x \frac{2ie^{it}}{2e^{it}-1}\,dt,$$

you have a continuous function of $x$, and indeed we have

$$I(x) = \log (2e^{ix} - 1)$$

for some value of the logarithm, but that value depends *continuously* on $x$. When $x$ increases from $0$ to $2\pi$, the curve described by $2e^{it}-1$ winds once around the origin, so the imaginary part of the logarithm increases from $0$ to $2\pi i$, and $I(2\pi) = 2\pi i$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I think I partially understand your answer if I look at the [Riemann surface plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eejkdpkvvgs) of $log(z)$.

Comment: Also, the integral is $\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 2} \frac{dz}{z-1}$, and by the Cauchy integral theorem, the integral is the same as $\int_{\lvert z-1\rvert = 1} \frac{dz}{z-1}$. If you paremetrise the second integral per $z = 1 + e^{it}$, you get $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{it}}{(1+e^{it})-1}\,dt = \int_0^{2\pi} i\,dt = 2\pi i$.

Comment: Now that is a useful comment!  I thought the Cauchy integral theorem required analicity inside the entire curve, but it just requires analicity in between the two paths.  Awesome.